# How to use django countries in registration form?

Tags: django, django-countries

I am trying to add django-countries in a registration form that will be used with django-allauth. As per instructions https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries I created a model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # Other things
    country = CountryField()
```

And a form

from django_countries.data import COUNTRIES

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    # Other stuff
    country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COUNTRIES, required=True)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        # Other Stuff
        user.userprofile.country = self.cleaned_data['country']
```

But when I visit the /accounts/signup/ page I get the form but for the countries select I get

```
<p><label for="id_country">Country:</label> <select id="id_country" name="country">
<option value="G">Q</option>
<option value="I">D</option>
<option value="K">Y</option>
 ...
```

Instead of country code and country name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set choices like this:

```
from django_countries import countries
COUNTRY_CHOICES = tuple(countries)

class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES, required=True)
```